# issue with the image and container getting complete width of the screen

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4, background-image

I have added an image with a basic hover effect.
The image is leaving space on both the side of the screen. Even I have added background-size: cover and width:100%

Please guide me where I am wrong.

here are my codes

```
    <div class="container">
      <img
        src="d8282202e8adb36a20e88d27ffc3b15e.jpg"
        alt="headerimage"
        class="image"
      />
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text"><h3>I AM RAJ JAIN</h3></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS codes

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px; 
  background-size: cover;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` element has a default margin which is causing the space around your image.

Add this to the top of your css:

```
body {margin: 0;}
```

[image]

Comment: /Users/rajjain/Desktop/Screenshot 2020-08-08 at 1.36.53 AM.png

I am still getting the same issue.
while space on both the side of the screen

Comment: You might have something else causing the issue. Could you post the full html?

Comment: only that specific container is creating problem. Rest is working fine.
Can you please check

Comment: I see what your issue is now. what are the dimensions of your background image?

Comment: 2560 × 1080 dimensions of the image

Comment: I created an image of that size and it's working fine for me. Not the answer you want to hear unfortunately. What browser are you testing in? I'm using Chrome latest version.